# Why was this question automatically closed (and later deleted)?

Tags: support

I had posted this a while ago:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57219993/app-frozen-inside-wpfgfx-v0400-dll-utility-polygonbounds-and-utility-pathgeometr

more recently I noticed it was closed, I think automatically? And later deleted. Was this because it had received little attention?

This other question was posted recently, which had some similarities: [Access Violation exception in WPF application and DirectX rasterizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868065/access-violation-exception-in-wpf-application-and-directx-rasterizer)

I don't know what the source of these errors are, but if its some esoteric and somewhat rare problem, automatic closure isn't doing any favors here. If they were left open long enough there is more of a possibility of someone having enough breadcrumbs to follow to provide useful answers.

Comment: The question has never been closed. It has been deleted automatically since it has zero score and no answers. See [this meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222).

Comment: If you click the [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) link in the message at the top of the question page that tells you the post was deleted you will see the [roomba help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) which explains when posts are automatically deleted. It's not exactly obvious that you'll find the explanation there but then again good UX was never a design goal for SO.

Comment: @ivarni thank you, I hadn't looked at many deleted questions before, I didn't notice that!  I guess this one fell into the "abandoned" category.;

Comment: the timeline shows "Scheduled: RemoveAbandonedQuestions"

Comment: @toolic in the edit history (if that's the timeline you mean) all I can see is "Post Deleted by Community♦ occurred Aug 1 at 0:01". Maybe I don't have access to the details?

Comment: not history... timeline is the clock icon on left

Comment: @toolic ah-ha! Never used that feature before, thanks.

Comment: The button is pretty new, we used to have to edit the URL manually to get to that page.

Comment: [Rationale behind RemoveAbandonedQuestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341081/what-is-the-rationale-behind-removeabandonedquestions)

Comment: Also, if an answer is very important, and if the question gets re-opened (or re-asked) you can always give it a bounty